# glm translation of vec4 not working (x and y do not change) despite scale and rotate working fine

Tags: c++, glm-math

When using glm translation on a mat4 and multiplying it by a vec4, x and y are inexplicably completely unaffected and appear the same as if I had translated in the first place. Is there something I'm just not understanding?

```cpp
mat4 c = mat4(1.f);
c = translate(c, vec3(10, 10, 0))
vec4 dv1 = vec4(line1s[i].x, line1s[i].y, 1.f, 1.f) * c
```

x and y should be affected by this, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of multiplication is incorrect in your code. In your example:

```cpp
vec4 dv1 = vec4(line1s[i].x, line1s[i].y, 1.f, 1.f) * c;
```

You should multiply the matrix by the vector, not the other way around:

```cpp
vec4 dv1 = c * vec4(line1s[i].x, line1s[i].y, 1.f, 1.f);
```

As explained in [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136573/multiply-matrix4x4-with-vec4), the correct formula for matrix-vector multiplication is:

```
(x*a + y*b + z*c + w*d;
 x*e + y*f + z*g + w*h;
 x*i + y*j + z*k + w*l;
 x*m + y*n + z*o + w*p)
```

So, when you multiply a matrix `c` by a vector `vec4(line1s[i].x, line1s[i].y, 1.f, 1.f)`, the translation part of the matrix (last column) will affect the resulting vector's x and y components as expected.

Make sure that the w component of the vec4 is set to 1, as mentioned in [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106287/glm-translate-matrix-does-not-translate-the-vector) and [gamedev.net](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/635073-how-can-i-transform-a-glmvec3-by-a-glmmat4/5010982/), which is required for translations to work correctly in homogeneous coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplications and multiplications of matrices with vectors are not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). The [glm-math](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/index.html) operations work like the corresponding GLSL operations. See [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations).
Therefore, the vector has to be multiplied to the matrix from the right.

```cpp
vec4 dv1 = c * vec4(line1s[i].x, line1s[i].y, 1.f, 1.f)
```